# Object.prototype returns empty object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

While I execute `Object.prototype` in browser console, i am getting all the properties and methods available inside `Object.prototype`. This is as expected but when i am executing exactly the same thing in NodeJS  terminal I am getting an empty object `{}`. Could anyone please explain me why its like this? I have attached screenshots of both.

[image: Browser]

[image: Terminal]

Comment: This is purely the way the two different systems choose to display an object.

Comment: @lonesomeday Well `{"key": "value"}` will display as `{"key": "value"}`, not as `{}`. Are you sure?

Comment: @Ivan Yes. The difference is that Node doesn't display non-enumerable properties, whereas the Chrome console displays them faded out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is because the console.log() in node use util.inspect(), which uses Object.keys() on objects, and it returns enumerable properties only.  And `Object.prototype`  contains non-enumerable properties, that is why it returns empty node.

Similar behavior can be observed in the below snippet, when we `console.log(Object.prototype)` it logs an empty `{}`;

```js
console.log(Object.prototype);
```

But when we explicitly define an enumerable property in `Object.prototype` it logs an object containing that property :

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'property1', {
  value: 42,
  enumerable : true
});
console.log(Object.prototype)
```

For [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: I would add that there is no agreed-upon standard for how an inspector (debugger, console, etc...) should display things, thus different environments choose slightly different implementations.

Comment: Why are props of `Object.prototype` not enumerable by default?

Answer (score 13):

By the way, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` if you want to know or access these properties.

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)
[ 'hasOwnProperty',
  'constructor',
  'toString',
  'toLocaleString',
  'valueOf',
  'isPrototypeOf',
  'propertyIsEnumerable',
  '__defineGetter__',
  '__lookupGetter__',
  '__defineSetter__',
  '__lookupSetter__',
  '__proto__' ]
```

It won't list other properties you might find in chrome dev console like scope or the value of promises. But it's good enough!