# Accessing a object's non enumerable properties

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Following this question: *[`Object.prototype` returns empty object in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233812/object-prototype-returns-empty-object-in-node?noredirect=1#comment89446807_51233812)* which asked

> Why doesn't `console.log(Object.prototype)` log the expected object and instead returns `{}`.

Here was the answer:

> It is because the `console.log` [...] uses `Object.keys()` on objects, and it **returns enumerable properties only**. And `Object.prototype` contains non-enumerable properties, that is why it returns an empty node.
>
> - [Amrender Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6514231/amrender-singh)

---

I was wondering how I could output all properties of a given object (for instance `Object.prototype`). As shown by another answer, using `getOwnPropertyNames` works fine:

```js
const ObjectPrototype = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype).reduce((object, name) => {

  object[name] = Object.prototype[name];

  return object;

}, {});

console.log(
  ObjectPrototype
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I thought I could extract the *hidden* properties of a given object this way. But actually, it doesn't fully work.

Here's an easier example: the object I'm inspecting is the object `{mykey: 'value'}`. Chrome gives me its property (`console.log` does too) but also its prototype, `__proto__` greyed out:

[image]

```js
let object = { mykey: 'value' };

object = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).reduce((acc, name) => {

  acc[name] = object[name];

  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(
  object
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The above only returns one property. I was expecting to also have `__proto__`. **Is there a way to show all of one's properties including *hidden* ones? Or do I manually have to access it: i.e. reduce `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object.__proto__)`?**

---

PS: or in other words, how does Chrome handle *hidden* properties?

Comment: What you are looking for is a foreach loop, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440001/iterate-over-object-keys-in-node-js

Comment: At least on Chrome, my update should output `object` almost exactly as the developer console does.

Comment: You cannot access hidden properties, that's why they are *hidden*. Chrome shows it because the debugger is more powerful than what JS alone can do, and it shows it with the confusing name `__proto__` suggesting that it's a normal property. (That said, you can access the prototype through `Object.getPrototypeOf`, but it's not possible in general to access hidden properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function, let's call it `getAllPropertyNames()`, that iterates through the prototype chain of the object and accumulates the properties of each level:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames (o) {
  let propertyNames = []

  for (let proto = o; proto !== null; proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)) {
    propertyNames = propertyNames.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto))
  }

  return propertyNames
}

console.log(getAllPropertyNames({ mykey: 'value' }))
```

These properties aren't hidden, they're just inherited, which is why `getOwnPropertyNames()` does not include them. They're not specific to the object, but rather everything that inherits from `Object.prototype`.

#### Update

I'm going to attempt something a little unconventional, but should produce the desired output:

```js
// probably could be named better
// feel free to suggest one in comments
function asEnumerable (o) {
  const acc = Object.create(null)

  for (let oProto = o, aProto = acc; oProto !== null; oProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(oProto), aProto = aProto.__proto__) {
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(oProto)) {
      aProto[key] = oProto[key]
    }

    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(oProto) !== null) {
      aProto.__proto__ = Object.create(null)
    }
  }

  return acc
}

console.log(asEnumerable({ mykey: 'value' }))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%!important}
```

This implementation *does* abide to the specification, since it does not treat `__proto__` as if it modifies inheritance of the object, but simply as a normal property on `acc` and `aProto`.

Comment: Just use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of the deprecated `__proto__`

Comment: @Bergi `Object.getPrototypeOf` does not allow `__proto__` to be reconfigured as `enumerable`. Since I'm using `Object.defineProperty(..., '__proto__', ...)` in that example already, there's no point in attempting to avoid it in other cases.

Comment: In an object that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`, you can use `__proto__` like any other property, you don't even need to make it enumerable explicitly. And it's not the deprecated `__proto__` getter/setter, which you still should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, can make ues of recursion

```js
// function to print all attributes for some object 
function getPropertyNames (Obj, prev = []) {
  if (Obj) {
    return getPropertyNames(
      Obj.prototype || Obj.__proto__, 
      prev.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Obj))
    )
  }
  return prev.sort()
}
```