# Blob doesn't parse to image when fetching profilePhoto from Microsoft Graph server-side NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api, blob, fetch-api

The following fetch outputs `Blob {}`, which I presume is empty data, and why attempts to parse to a usable image (i.e., `URL.createObjectURL()`) fail.

**server.js**

```js
fetch(Queries.getUserPhotoURL, Queries.getDataBody(loginData.access_token))
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(userPhotoData => {
       console.log(userPhotoData);
    });
```

**ms-queries.js**

```js
export const getUserPhotoURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value";

export function getDataBody(token) {
    return {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "Host": "graph.microsoft.com"
        }
    };
}
```

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but the response code is `200 OK` and other Graph queries work fine, so I assume the problem is how I'm handling the response. And [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) haven't been much help.

Thanks for any advice!

**Clarification & update** - the following line outputs this error.

```js
var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(userPhotoData);
```

```
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "obj" argument must be an instance of Blob. Received an instance of Blob
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at Function.createObjectURL (node:internal/url:963:13)
    at file:///home/[redacted]/[redacted]/server.js:199:52
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: The log `{}` is because a `Blob` instance doesn't have any enumerable property, and node's console only outputs enumerable properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233812/object-prototype-returns-empty-object-in-node For the `createObjectURL` issue however that would be something else, but if that failed, then you'd have an error in the console. So you probably have an issue at using this blob: URL. Can you show this part please?

Comment: Brilliant thanks - that makes plenty of sense - I've updated with the error upon attempting to parse to URL.